# Inserting controller logic between model and view when using Interface Builder, NSObjectController sub-classes, and bindings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

I've been struggling to understand the best way to insert controller logic when using IB, NSObjectController sub-classes and bindings.

I need to insert controller logic between the model and the view, and I'm struggling to find an elegant way to do so. Yes, you can send actions to the file owner and handle controller logic in there, but when some core data models can extend across fifty entities or more with deep relationship structures, this starts to mount up to an incredible amount of boiler-plate code.

A very simplified example would be this; imagine you have an entity with four string attributes myTextWinter, myTextSpring, myTextSummer, myTextAutumn. You have a view which connects to this in IB via an NSObjectController. Now, say the user can select which 'Season' they wish to view by choosing Spring, Summer, Autumn, Winter from a Menu somewhere - when that season is selected, I would like to display the appropriate season's text.

In this simplified example I could probably fetch the object in the NSDocument sub-class, create a property called mySeasonText which I bind to in my view, and then check my NSUserDefaults for the appropriate season and route the requests to the appropriate attribute in the model.

The problem comes when I have fifty entities, some with relationships some two, three or more deep, each with their own set of season specific text attributes that I wish to switch between when selecting from the Season menu. Or if I have a bunch of nsarraycontrollers chained together to access objects at a deeper, and deeper level.

To date, I've been doing the following; adding a property in each of my model objects called 'mySeasonText', then grabbing the setting from my controller setting, and routing to the appropriate season. I refresh these objects whenever a new item in the menu is selected.

Whilst this works and eliminates an absolute ton of boiler-plate code, my controller logic is now in my model.

There must be a better way! Could someone please point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Too much text. You should put this question more succinctly.

Comment: Thanks, have edited down. For reference here's what I've already tried (cut from answer above) I've also tried to sub-class nsarraycontroller (with no luck whatsoever) to 'wrap' each object in the array with a proxy object which is aware of the current 'season' setting and then overrides setValueForUndefinedKey: and valueForUndefinedKey: to the appropriate property in the wrapped object. This feels like a nasty hack and I'm not sure it will even work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky topic. Apple even mentions these challenges in its own documentation:

> By using the bindings technology, you can easily create a Cocoa MVC application whose views directly observe model objects to receive notifications of state changes. However, there is a theoretical problem with this design. View objects and model objects should be the most reusable objects in an application. […] Design-wise, it's best to keep model and view objects separate from each other, because that enhances their reusability.

The design pattern you are looking for is a [Mediating Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH14-SW7) - a way to use the cocoa-bindings classes to insert controller logic:

> Mediating controllers are typically ready-made objects that you drag from the Interface Builder library. You can configure [Mediating controllers] to establish the bindings between properties of view objects and properties of the controller object, and then between those controller properties and specific properties of a model object. As a result, when users change a value displayed in a view object, the new value is automatically communicated to a model object for storage—via the mediating controller; and when a property of a model changes its value, that change is communicated to a view for display.

Here is how I like to think of them: Have you ever seen a movie or TV show where two characters need to talk, but they don't speak any of the same languages? They find someone else (or in a comedy 5 other people) who each have one language in common, and they communicate by playing a giant game of translation telephone.

Mediating controllers are kind of like that.

As your application grows they learn all the super specific rules about where to look for *this one thing on this one view*. This is the kind of code that an app *needs* to run, but you rightly feel that it is *nasty* when put in your model.

For several specific and detailed examples, Apple provides this amazingly detailed document: [Bindings Message Flow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/cocoabindings/Concepts/MessageFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002149-BCICADHC).

For some really good discussions about this and related MVC + Bindings please see:

- [MVC and cocoa bindings best practices question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356997/mvc-and-cocoa-bindings-best-practices-question)
- [Why use NSObjectController?](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/215378-why-use-nsobjectcontroller.html)
- [Replacing model objects using an NSArrayController](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/281321-replacing-model-objects-using-an-nsarraycontroller.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree, a Mediating Controller is what I need, and it sounds like this mediating controller should handle _another controller object_ which then forwards to the model. But what would this look like in practice? Would it be best to extend NSObjectController and NSArrayController which are already built to work with Core Data and in the case of arrays 'handle tasks like sorting, selection, adding and removing objects'. They actually do use a proxy object to wrap the model object. But how would I make my own?

Comment: A Mediating Controller chain can be very simple or very complex - so it depends on your specific needs and architecture. A simple example would be if I had a very complicated view with, say, a notifications area, a settings area, and a messages area. I could make a single Mediating Controller for that view that, instead of dealing with a bunch of models, talked to a Notifications Controller, a Settings Controller, and a Messages Controller - each of those only talking to a handful of models. This way related code is kept together, and it's easy to reuse the controllers elsewhere.